# is Quarkus support aws lambda with graphQL end point which can be exposed throughAPI gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, quarkus

I tried to do it using
'io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-lambda-http'
'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-graphql'

but getting following exception in cloudwatch

2022-06-15 12:40:28,734 ERROR [qua.ama.lam.http] (main) Request Failure: java.lang.ClassCastException: class lambdainternal.api.LambdaContext cannot be cast to class io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AmazonLambdaContext (lambdainternal.api.LambdaContext is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AmazonLambdaContext is in unnamed module of loader lambdainternal.CustomerClassLoader @433c675d)

Comment: I was able to resolve it by using io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-lambda-rest extension instead of io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-lambda-http